# how can i open the twitter button in a popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

hey im using the twitter widgets.js and angular.js and im trying to make the twitter open in a pop up

this is my code , its work but open in a diffrent page 
have any idea? 
i tried window.open and its not works for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
  <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-app="myApp">

 twitter data-text="Your text: {{file.name}}" ></a>



<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.directive('twitter', [
        function () {
            return {
                link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
                            attr.url,
                            element[0],
                            function (el) { }, {
                                count: 'none',
                                text: attr.text

                            }
                        );
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
 </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: `window.open` is the way to go. You maybe forgot to initialize the JS part? Or your browser is blocking opening new windows. check this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hansfranz/pen/OjMzEV)